# Power BI Time Series Forecasting Chart :: R script error. Loading required package: XML

Tags: r, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I want to use Time Series Forecasting Chart.

Reading the Overview I noticed that:

> Supports R versions: R 3.3.1, R 3.3.0, MRO 3.3.1, MRO 3.3.0, MRO 3.2.2

[image]

Which is OK for me.

So I went online an I downloaded [Microsoft R Open 3.2.2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51205). (the only compatible version of MRO I can find online)

But once installed and correctly setup in Power BI Desktop I receive this error:

```
Feedback Type:
Frown (Error)

Error Message:
R script error.
Loading required package: XML
Loading required package: methods
Loading required package: htmlwidgets
Warning messages:
1: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called 'htmlwidgets'
2: In libraryRequireInstall("htmlwidgets") :
  *** The package: 'htmlwidgets' was not installed ***
Loading required package: ggplot2
Warning messages:
1: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called 'ggplot2'
2: In libraryRequireInstall("ggplot2") :
  *** The package: 'ggplot2' was not installed ***
Loading required package: plotly
Warning messages:
1: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called 'plotly'
2: In libraryRequireInstall("plotly") :
  *** The package: 'plotly' was not installed ***
Loading required package: caTools
Warning messages:
1: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called 'caTools'
2: In libraryRequireInstall("caTools") :
  *** The package: 'caTools' was not installed ***
Loading required package: scales
Warning messages:
1: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called 'scales'
2: In libraryRequireInstall("scales") :
  *** The package: 'scales' was not installed ***
Loading required package: forecast
Warning messages:
1: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called 'forecast'
2: In libraryRequireInstall("forecast") :
  *** The package: 'forecast' was not installed ***
Loading required package: zoo
Warning messages:
1: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called 'zoo'
2: In libraryRequireInstall("zoo") :
  *** The package: 'zoo' was not installed ***
Loading required package: ggplot2
Warning messages:
1: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called 'ggplot2'
2: In libraryRequireInstall("ggplot2") :
  *** The package: 'ggplot2' was not installed ***
Error: could not find function "ets"
Execution halted


Stack Trace:
Host:Microsoft.PowerBI.Scripting.R.Exceptions.RScriptRuntimeException
Loading required package: XML
Loading required package: methods
Loading required package: htmlwidgets
Warning messages:
1: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called 'htmlwidgets'
2: In libraryRequireInstall("htmlwidgets") :
  *** The package: 'htmlwidgets' was not installed ***
Loading required package: ggplot2
Warning messages:
1: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called 'ggplot2'
2: In libraryRequireInstall("ggplot2") :
  *** The package: 'ggplot2' was not installed ***
Loading required package: plotly
Warning messages:
1: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called 'plotly'
2: In libraryRequireInstall("plotly") :
  *** The package: 'plotly' was not installed ***
Loading required package: caTools
Warning messages:
1: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called 'caTools'
2: In libraryRequireInstall("caTools") :
  *** The package: 'caTools' was not installed ***
Loading required package: scales
Warning messages:
1: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called 'scales'
2: In libraryRequireInstall("scales") :
  *** The package: 'scales' was not installed ***
Loading required package: forecast
Warning messages:
1: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called 'forecast'
2: In libraryRequireInstall("forecast") :
  *** The package: 'forecast' was not installed ***
Loading required package: zoo
Warning messages:
1: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called 'zoo'
2: In libraryRequireInstall("zoo") :
  *** The package: 'zoo' was not installed ***
Loading required package: ggplot2
Warning messages:
1: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called 'ggplot2'
2: In libraryRequireInstall("ggplot2") :
  *** The package: 'ggplot2' was not installed ***
Error: could not find function "ets"
Execution halted

   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Scripting.R.RScriptWrapper.RunScript(String originalScript, Int32 timeoutMs)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.R.RScriptHandler.GenerateVisual(ScriptHandlerOptions options)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.R.RScriptHandler.GenerateVisual(ScriptHandlerOptions options)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.ExploreHost.SemanticQuery.ScriptVisualCommandFlow.RunInternal(Stream dataShapeResultStream, QueryBindingDescriptor& bindingDescriptor)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.ExploreHost.SemanticQuery.ScriptVisualCommandFlow.Run(Stream dataShapeResultStream, QueryBindingDescriptor& bindingDescriptor)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.ExploreHost.SemanticQuery.ExecuteSemanticQueryFlow.TransformDataShapeResult(QueryCommand transformCommand, SemanticQueryDataShapeCommand command, Stream dataShapeResultStream, QueryBindingDescriptor& bindingDescriptor)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.ExploreHost.SemanticQuery.ExecuteSemanticQueryFlow.ExecuteDataQuery(IQueryResultDataWriter queryResultDataWriter, EngineDataModel engineDataModel, DataQuery query, Int32 queryId, ServiceErrorStatusCode& serviceErrorStatusCode, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.ExploreHost.SemanticQuery.ExecuteSemanticQueryFlow.ProcessAndWriteSemanticQueryCommands(IQueryResultsWriter queryResultsWriter, IList`1 queries, HashSet`1 pendingQueriesToCancel, EngineDataModel engineDataModel)

JavaScript:ShowErrorDialog
 at ErrorHostService.showErrorDialogCore(args)

Stack Trace Message:
R script error.

Invocation Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionExtensions.GetCurrentInvocationStackTrace()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.StackTraceInfo..ctor(String exceptionStackTrace, String invocationStackTrace, String exceptionMessage)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Telemetry.PowerBIUserFeedbackServices.GetStackTraceInfo(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Telemetry.PowerBIUserFeedbackServices.ReportException(IWindowHandle activeWindow, IUIHost uiHost, FeedbackPackageInfo feedbackPackageInfo, Exception e, Boolean useGDICapture)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<HandleException>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.PowerBIUnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Utilities.PowerBIFormUnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.ErrorHostService.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<ShowErrorDialogCore>b__0()
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Send(SendOrPostCallback d, Object state)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Services.UIBlockingService.AllowModalDialogs(Action action)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.HostServiceDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<ExecuteOnUIThreadAndHandlePromise>b__0()
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.HostServiceDispatcher.ExecuteOnUIThreadAndHandlePromise[T](Func`1 func, IPromiseStore promiseStore, Int64 promiseHandle)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.WebView2.WebView2Interop.InvokeCs(InteropCall call)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.WindowManager.ShowModal[T](T dialog, Func`1 showModalFunction)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<RunApplication>b__0()
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.IExceptionHandlerExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<HandleExceptionsWithNestedTasks>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.RunApplication(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.Main(String[] args)


PowerBINonFatalError:
{"AppName":"PBIDesktop","AppVersion":"2.124.2028.0","ModuleName":null,"Component":"Microsoft.PowerBI.Scripting.R.RScriptWrapper","Error":"Microsoft.PowerBI.Scripting.R.Exceptions.RScriptRuntimeException","MethodDef":"RunScript","ErrorOffset":"","ErrorCode":""}

AS Live Connection:
True

Performance Trace Logs:
C:\Users\FrancescoMantovani\Microsoft\Power BI Desktop Store App\PerformanceTraces.zip

Enabled Preview Features:
PBI_shapeMapVisualEnabled
PBI_qnaLiveConnect
PBI_b2bExternalDatasetSharing
PBI_enhancedTooltips
PBI_sparklines
PBI_scorecardVisual
PBI_NlToDax
PBI_fieldParametersSuperSwitch
PBI_angularRls
PBI_setLabelOnExportPdf
PBI_dynamicFormatString
PBI_oneDriveSave
PBI_oneDriveShare
PBI_newCard
PBI_buttonSlicerAuthoring
PBI_daxQueryView

Disabled Preview Features:
PBI_SpanishLinguisticsEnabled
PBI_onObject
PBI_backstageUI
PBI_useModernPublishDialogs
PBI_gitIntegration
PBI_modelExplorer
PBI_aiNarrativesVisual
PBI_qnaImproveLsdlCopilot

Disabled DirectQuery Options:
TreatHanaAsRelationalSource

Cloud:
GlobalCloud

PowerBIUserFeedbackServices_IsReported:
True

Formulas:


section Section1;
```

I don't even know where to start to debug here.

The problem is that I have no other version alternative:

- R 3.3.1 has no .exe install file
- R 3.3.0 has no .exe install file
- MRO 3.3.1 cannot be found online
- MRO 3.3.0 cannot be found online
- MRO 3.2.2 is the only available online but it give this error.

Comment: The github repo hasn't been updated in 6 years.  It might work with the latest version of R supported by Power BI (R 3.4.4), even if it isn't officially listed in the supported versions.  You might also be able to install the required R packages manually using the R script editor.  Otherwise you could try reaching out to the support email at pbicvsupport@microsoft.com

Comment: Thank you, I tried to use R 3.4.4 and is not working. I will try to contact them

Comment: Have you tried using the default Line Chart with Forecast options from the Analytics pane?

Comment: Totally agree with @SusanSwitzer - don't waste time on a no longer maintained custom visual and instead use the existing capabilities in PBI (which is probably why the visual is no longer being developed). See [Use the Analytics pane in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-analytics-pane#apply-forecasting)

Comment: Yes, I've used that and frankly it's horrible. The span between the MIN and the MAX it's simply too wide and there is little tuning for reducing the margin of error. Plus you cannot base the forecast on previous data (seasonality). It basically draws two divergent lines, like a funnel. That is not a forecast.

Comment: It's pretty good and you can tune it for seasonality, you have to adjust the settings for it. For example, try setting the seasonality to 12.

Comment: And the answer from Microsoft is: "We investigated your case and this visual is really not been maintained for a long period of time. Since any further development of this visual is not planned and it will not be supported, we will deprecate this visual in a nearest time. 
We apologize for any inconvenience this situation may have caused you. "

Comment: I [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77941139/rtools-3-3-incompatible-with-r-3-3-31#comment137406287_77941139) trying it anyway using a modern R. Have you done that? I don't consider R-3.4.4 "modern", I'd lean towards R-4 at a minimum, I see no reason to not try R-4.3.2 (current as of today).

Comment: @r2evans I tried with  R-4.3.2 and I receive the same error

Comment: Okay, thanks for checking that. Combining that with Microsoft's "deprecate" message, I think you need to shop for another visualization product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Power BI support and the reply was:

*"We investigated your case and this visual is really not been maintained for a long period of time. Since any further development of this visual is not planned and it will not be supported, we will deprecate this visual in a nearest time. We apologize for any inconvenience this situation may have caused you."*