# Rtools 3.3 incompatible with R 3.3.31

Tags: r, rtools

I have installed [R version 3.3.1](https://cran-archive.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/3.3.1/)

If I try to `install.packages("ggplot2")` I receive this error:

```
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but no version of Rtools compatible with the currently running version of R was found. Note that the following incompatible version(s) of Rtools were found:

  - Rtools 3.3 (installed at c:\Rtools)

Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
```

But this makes no sense because Rtools is in 3.3 version:
[image]

Comment: Must you use version 3.3? I am sure R has backward compatibility. Consider >=3.6. If not I would suggest to use msys2 for windows.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I can only use R 3.3.1, R 3.3.0, MRO 3.3.1, MRO 3.3.0, MRO 3.2.2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77921395/power-bi-time-series-forecasting-chart-r-script-error-loading-required-packa

Comment: Try installing Rtools 3.5 — it’s possible (though admittedly unlikely based on the documentation) that R 3.3.1 no longer works with Rtools 3.3. Either way, even if you manage to fix this particular issue you will probably encounter more issues getting this to run: R 3.3 is ancient, and most current packages no longer support it, so you will have to install old, archived package versions and their respective dependencies. I’m surprised that ‘ggplot2’ claims to still support R 3.3! — given that not all its dependencies do, this is probably not actually true.

Comment: That PowerBI tool has not been updated in April 2018 (https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-visuals-forcasting-exp/), not even any human-written issues since 2018. To me that suggests abandonware, even if Microsoft still has it available on its tool website. Here's something crazy ... looking at the files within the repo, the only time the string `3.3` comes up is in readme-text, the only other places I see dependencies are references to `"R"` (no version) ... how about you try it with modern R and Rtools?

Comment: Bottom line, though, I agree with KonradRudolph -- it's likely that many of the packages you want to use will require a newer version of R, either directly or one of their dependencies. As you find a package that does not work in R-3.3, you'll need to ask about workarounds for its functionality that you need, which may require Herculean workarounds. If you're lucky, PowerBI will "just work" with whatever R it finds. If not, and you need to proceed, then reach out to the tool devs ... though the first dev hasn't contributed on github at all since 2018, and the second dev since late 2022.

Comment: I opened a ticket with Power BI support. So far I tried with R 4.3.2, R 3.3.1,  MRO 3.2.2. None works

Comment: I contacted Power BI support and the reply was:

"We investigated your case and this visual is really not been maintained for a long period of time. Since any further development of this visual is not planned and it will not be supported, we will deprecate this visual in a nearest time. We apologize for any inconvenience this situation may have caused you."